# Display image form a variable URL on a jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

Hello guys I am working a web application using mongoose, node.js and express. 
I store path of image, on mongoose and just wondering how to display image that I uploaded on jade. Because I have absolute URL of image:`imgURL ='/Users/Larry_Li/Desktop/uploads/3937b0008d912eee451254296a8ce7cb.png'`

```
res.render('preview',{imgURL:imgURL});
```

when I pass it to preview.jade:

```
<img src= '#{ imgURL }'; />
```

The URL is always resolved as `localhost:3000`+`'/Users/Larry_Li/Desktop/uploads/3937b0008d912eee451254296a8ce7cb.png`.
My question is how display this local image by using path I have?

Answer (score 0):

1. your preview.jade code isn't jade, that would be `img(src=imgURL)`
2. use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve files from your uploads directory
3. use [path.basename](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext) to get the filename